# Is it possible to calculte the BIC in LASSO cases if p>n

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, model-comparison

I thinks the question should be clear. Is it possible to calculate the BIC criterion in cases where p>n with the "traditional" BIC Formula ?

I know that there are some extensions of information criteria allowing to calculate them with p>n. I am just askin for the Standard BIC case